# How to instantiate an object from an array of properties

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

I can't find a way to get this kind of thing working :

```
// I want to achieve managing the structure of the object here and only here
var objectAPropertiesList = ["aProp", "bProp", "cProp"];

// Object with constructor
function ObjectA(properties) {
    objectAPropertiesList.forEach(function (property) {
        this[property] = properties[property];
    });
}
// instantiation
myObjectA = new ObjectA({"aProp": 1, "bProp": 2, "cProp": 3});

// keeps giving me '{}' !
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObjectA));
```

Can someone explain how please ?

Comment: Use `for (const property of myObjectPropertiesList) {` and it'll work.

Comment: thank you ! @hindMost : I thought `["blah blah", "anything',  ...]` was the array notation whereas `{"propA":"valueA", "propB":"valueB", ...}` was the Object one ?...

Comment: @Bergi I don't see the relation between my post anf the one you indicated as being a duplicate...

Comment: It tells you why the `this[property]` assignment inside the callback doesn't work

Comment: ok I understand. `.forEach()` calls another function here, I didn't pay attention to it ! By the way, I [just see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) that one can pass a *thisArg* as second argument to `.forEach`, which allows to use it too